# How do I use PHP's stream_select() with a zlib filter?

Tags: php, sockets, filter, stream, zlib

I currently have a server daemon written in PHP which accepts incoming connections and creates network streams for them using the `stream_socket_*` functions and polls active streams using `stream_select()`.  I'd like to be able to add a zlib filter (using `string_filter_append()`) to an arbitrary stream, but when I do, I get an error telling me that `stream_select()` can't be used to poll a filtered stream.

How can I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pipe, and add the filter to the pipe instead.

This will allow you to use stream_select on the stream, and the pipe will serve as a buffer for zlib.

Read the raw data from the select()ed stream, write it to the pipe, and read the decoded data on the other side :)

```
list($in, $out) = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX, STREAM_SOCK_STREAM, 0);

stream_filter_append($out, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
stream_set_blocking($out, 0);

while (stream_select(...)) {
    // assuming that $stream is non blocking
    stream_copy_to_stream($stream, $in);

    $decoded_data = stream_get_contents($out);
}
```

The same can probably be achieved with a php://memory stream.

Comment: Thank you, this method does seem to allow me to circumvent the limitation, however I am using "zlib.deflate", and I am not copying stream-to-stream, but rather, just using fwrite() to send server-generated data through the outbound network streams.  Using this method, stream_get_contents($out) returns the 2-byte zlib header and nothing else.  If I write the same data to a file, rather than writing to $in and reading $out, the compressed $data is written completely.  Is there something about this method that would prevent reading the complete compressed data from $out?

Comment: The filter may be writing to the stream only after some amount of data has been written; try writing more data. Also try with the zlib.deflate filter on the write side with STREAM_FILTER_WRITE VS on the read side with STREAM_FILTER_READ.