# Using zlib filter with a socket pair

Tags: php, sockets, stream, zlib

For some reason, the `zlib.deflate` filter doesn't seem to be working with socket pairs generated by `stream_socket_pair()`.  All that can be read from the second socket is the two-byte zlib header, and everything after that is NULL.

Example:

```
<?php
list($in, $out) = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX,
                                     STREAM_SOCK_STREAM,
                                     STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);

stream_filter_append($in, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
stream_set_blocking($in, 0);
stream_set_blocking($out, 0);

fwrite($in, 'Some big long string.');
$compressed = fread($out, 1024);
var_dump($compressed);

fwrite($in, 'Some big long string, take two.');
$compressed = fread($out, 1024);
var_dump($compressed);

fwrite($in, 'Some big long string - third time is the charm?');
$compressed = fread($out, 1024);
var_dump($compressed);
```

Output:

```
string(2) "x�"
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

If I comment out the call to `stream_filter_append()`, the stream writing/reading functions correctly, with the data being dumped in its entirety all three times, and if I direct the zlib filtered stream into a file instead of through the socket pair, the compressed data is written correctly.  So both parts function correctly separately, but not together.  Is this a PHP bug that I should report, or an error on my part?

*This question is branched from a solution to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207484/how-do-i-use-phps-stream-select-with-a-zlib-filter).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through [the C source code](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/zlib/zlib_filter.c?revision=316627&view=markup), the problem is that the filter always lets [zlib's `deflate()` function](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Basic) decide how much data to accumulate before producing compressed output. The deflate filter does not create a new data bucket to pass on unless `deflate()` outputs some data (see line 235) or the `PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE` flag bit is set (line 250). That's why you only see the header bytes until you close `$in`; the first call to `deflate()` outputs the two header bytes, so `data->strm.avail_out` is 2 and a new bucket is created for these two bytes to pass on.

Note that `fflush()` does not work because of a known issue with the zlib filter. See:  [Bug #48725 Support for flushing in zlib stream](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48725).

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a nice work-around to this. I started writing a filter in PHP by extending `php_user_filter`, but quickly ran into the problem that `php_user_filter` does not expose the flag bits, only whether `flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE` (the fourth parameter to the `filter()` method, a boolean argument commonly named `$closing`). You would need to modify the C sources yourself to fix Bug #48725. Alternatively, re-write it.

Personally I would consider re-writing it because there seems to be a few eyebrow-raising issues with the code:

- `status = deflate(&(data->strm), flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE ? Z_FULL_FLUSH : (flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_INC ? Z_SYNC_FLUSH : Z_NO_FLUSH));` seems odd because when writing, I don't know why `flags` would be anything other than `PSFS_FLAG_NORMAL`. Is it possible to write & flush at the same time? In any case, handling the flags should be done outside of the `while` loop through the "in" bucket brigade, like how `PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE` is handled outside of this loop.
- Line 221, the `memcpy` to `data->strm.next_in` seems to ignore the fact that `data->strm.avail_in` may be non-zero, so the compressed output might skip some data of a write. See, for example, the following text from the zlib manual:

  > If not all input can be processed (because there is not enough room in the output buffer), `next_in` and `avail_in` are updated and processing will resume at this point for the next call of `deflate()`.

  In other words, it is possible that `avail_in` is non-zero.
- The `if` statement on line 235, `if (data->strm.avail_out < data->outbuf_len)` should probably be `if (data->strm.avail_out)` or perhaps `if (data->strm.avail_out > 2)`.
- <s>I'm not sure why `*bytes_consumed = consumed;` isn't `*bytes_consumed += consumed;`. The example streams at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-register.php all use `+=` to update `$consumed`.</s>

**EDIT:** `*bytes_consumed = consumed;` is correct. [The standard filter implementations](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/filters.c?revision=316627&view=markup) all use `=` rather than `+=` to update the `size_t` value pointed to by the fifth parameter. Also, even though `$consumed += ...` on the PHP side effectively translates to `+=` on the `size_t` (see lines 206 and 231 of [`ext/standard/user_filters.c`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/user_filters.c?revision=316627&view=markup)), the native filter function is called with either a `NULL` pointer or a pointer to a `size_t` set to 0 for the fifth argument (see lines 361 and 452 of [`main/streams/filter.c`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/streams/filter.c?revision=316627&view=markup)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  I implemented the same project in Ruby and ended up having to pass `Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH` as the second argument to `Zlib::deflate()` to get it working.  I assume that this is writing and then immediately flushing after the write.  I notice that PHP is only using `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` if the `PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_INC` flag is set, but as you said, the flag bits don't seem to be exposed.

Answer (score 3):

I had worked on the PHP source code and found a fix.

To understand what happens I had traced the code during a

```
....
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++) {
    fwrite($s[0], ...);
    fread($s[1], ...);
    fflush($s[0], ...);
    fread($s[1], ...);
    }
```

loop and I found that the `deflate` function is never called with the `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` flag set because no new data are present into the `backets_in` brigade.

My fix is to manage the (*`PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_INC` flag is set `AND` no iterations are performed on deflate function* case) extending the

```
if (flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE) {
```

managing `FLUSH_INC` too:

```
if (flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_CLOSE || (flags & PSFS_FLAG_FLUSH_INC && to_be_flushed)) {
```

[This downloadable patch](https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=48725&patch=zlib-filter-flush-fix.patch&revision=latest) is for `debian squeeze` version of PHP but the current git version of the file is closer to it so I suppose to port the fix is simply (few lines).

If some side effect arises please contact me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the stream after the write to flush it before the data will come in from the read.

```
list($in, $out) = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX,
                                     STREAM_SOCK_STREAM,
                                     STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);

stream_filter_append($out, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
stream_set_blocking($out, 0);
stream_set_blocking($in, 0);

fwrite($out, 'Some big long string.');
fclose($out);
$compressed = fread($in, 1024);
echo "Compressed:" . bin2hex($compressed) . "<br>\n";


list($in, $out) = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX,
                                     STREAM_SOCK_STREAM,
                                     STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);

stream_filter_append($out, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
stream_set_blocking($out, 0);
stream_set_blocking($in, 0);


fwrite($out, 'Some big long string, take two.');
fclose($out);
$compressed = fread($in, 1024);
echo "Compressed:" . bin2hex($compressed) . "<br>\n";

list($in, $out) = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX,
                                     STREAM_SOCK_STREAM,
                                     STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);

stream_filter_append($out, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
stream_set_blocking($out, 0);
stream_set_blocking($in, 0);

fwrite($out, 'Some big long string - third time is the charm?');
fclose($out);
$compressed = fread($in, 1024);
echo "Compressed:" . bin2hex($compressed) . "<br>\n";
```

That produces:
Compressed:789c0bcecf4d5548ca4c57c8c9cf4b57282e29cacc4bd70300532b079c
Compressed:789c0bcecf4d5548ca4c57c8c9cf4b57282e29cacc4bd7512849cc4e552829cfd70300b1b50b07
Compressed:789c0bcecf4d5548ca4c57c8c9cf4b57282e29ca0452ba0a25199945290a259940c9cc62202f55213923b128d71e008e4c108c

Also I switched the $in and $out because writing to $in confused me.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this solution is not a feasible one.  The overhead for opening/closing the sockets after every write would be prohibitive in and of itself, but this is also destroying the zlib filter after every write, which would break the implementation.  The point of using a zlib filter is so that successive writes use the same filter.  Surely there must be a way to flush without closing?  I've tried `fflush()` before, without much luck.  **Edit:** To be more clear, sending the header every write would break the implementation, as it's only meant to be sent once.