# PHP/Ruby Zlib Equivalence

Tags: php, ruby, zlib

I'm wondering what the PHP equivalent to this code is:

```
require "zlib"
foo = Zlib::Deflate.new()
bar = "bar"
puts foo.deflate(bar, Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH).unpack('H*')
puts foo.deflate(bar, Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH).unpack('H*')
puts foo.deflate(bar, Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH).unpack('H*')
foo.close()
```

Output:

```
789c4a4a2c02000000ffff
4a4a2c02000000ffff
022200000000ffff
```

I have tried using `gzdeflate()`, `gzcompress()`, a `compress.zlib://` stream and more, but can't find the correct equivalent.

**Edit:**

It should be noted that the use-case for this problem is a persistent Zlib stream for a TCP connection, *not* for simple web page compression.  In other words, successive calls to the deflate should be using the *same* Zlib stream.  PHP currently allows this, but provides no method for manually flushing (e.g. `SYNC_FLUSH`), and will wait to flush until the stream is closed.  This is not acceptable for my use-case, as I need to be able to flush at any given point to send the compressed data up to that point to the remote client.

**Edit #2:**

Please see also [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508762/using-zlib-filter-with-a-socket-pair) for a more in-depth analysis into why PHP doesn't allow `SYNC_FLUSH`.  I'm looking for a hack or workaround to this, until PHP is eventually patched to address it (unfortunately, if it *is* patched, it will likely be in the 5.4 branch, which I won't be able to use for quite a long time, making the workaround that much more important).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a PECL `http` extension especially for your needs. :)

```
<?php
$stream = new HttpDeflateStream(HttpDeflateStream::FLUSH_SYNC);
echo bin2hex($stream->update('bar')) . PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($stream->update('bar')) . PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($stream->update('bar')) . PHP_EOL;

$ php test.php
789c4a4a2c02000000ffff
4a4a2c02000000ffff
022200000000ffff
```

Hope that helps. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.httpdeflatestream.php

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo bin2hex(gzcompress('bar'));
789c4b4a2c0200025d0136
php > echo bin2hex(gzdeflate('bar'));
4b4a2c0200
```

I have found an interesting article about the subject: http://www.agileweboperations.com/how-inflate-and-deflate-data-ruby-and-php

---

I played a bit more and came to this:

```
include 'zlib.php';
$foo = new Zlib_Deflate();
$bar = 'bar';
echo bin2hex($foo->deflate($bar)) . "\n";
echo bin2hex($foo->deflate($bar)) . "\n";
echo bin2hex($foo->deflate($bar)) . "\n";
$foo->close();
```

Output:

```
789c4b4a2c02000000ffff
4a4a2c02000000ffff
0223000000ffff
```

Below, the contents of "zlib.php":

```
class Zlib_Deflate
{
    private $stream = '';
    private $deflated = '';
    public function deflate($string)
    {
        $new = empty($this->stream);
        $this->stream .= $string;
        $deflated = gzdeflate($this->stream);
        $deflated_diff = $this->diff($this->deflated, $deflated);
        $this->deflated = $deflated;
        return ($new ? pack('H*', '789c') : '') . $deflated_diff . pack('H*', '0000ffff');
    }
    private function diff($str1, $str2)
    {
        $result = '';
        $max = strlen($str2);
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
            if ($str1[$i] != $str2[$i])
                break;
        return substr($str2, $i);
    }
    public function close()
    {
        $this->stream = '';
    }
}
```

Of course, we can't take this seriously. It is a kindergarten code.

Anyway, it brings some light and give a few clues about the issue...

The function wanted is `gzdeflate` indeed. In the article linked above, you learn how to easily make the Ruby deflate work as the PHP one. However, the opposite (make PHP deflate work as RubY) is not simple.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, however, the opposite scenario (making PHP work as Ruby) is specifically what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have looked into Ruby's Zlib source code (I suggest you do it), and it seemed to me very complex / advanced / "serious stuff" - not something to be translated in a couple of hours...